# Determining number of changes within groups along with observations at the time of transition

Tags: r, panel-data

Say I have the following panel dataframe (the reproducible toy example follows):

```
ID <- c(12232,12232,12232,12232,12232,14452,14452,14452)
Time <- c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3)
y1 <- c(2.3,7.8,4.5,3.4,2.3,1.2,0.5,1.9)
State <- c("a","a","a","b","a","c","c","b")
DataFrame <- cbind(ID,Time,y1,State)
```

I would 
I'd like to know whether there is some way of identifying the individuals transitioning between states (State) along with the observations at the time they occur.
Desired output: A dataframe yielding the IDs of individuals transitioning between State along with y1 at the time of the transition, e.g, something along the lines of

```
ID     transition y1
12232   a -> b    4.5
12232   b -> a    3.4
14452   c -> b    0.5
```

Of course the transition field does not need to have that format...ab and bc would work just as well, what matters is that
it works by groups (ID, as it is panel data) and matches the transitions between states with the features at the time they occured.

Many thanks in advance, this site has saved my life a lot of times :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
    library(data.table)
    df <- data.frame(DataFrame)
    setDT(df)
    df[, lead := shift(State, type = "lead"), by = ID]
    df[State != lead, transition := paste0(State, " -> ", lead)]
    df <- df[!(is.na(transition)), ]
    df <- df[, c("ID", "transition", "y1")]
```

Output:

```
      ID transition  y1
1: 12232     a -> b 4.5
2: 12232     b -> a 3.4
3: 14452     c -> b 0.5
```

Comment: Great, that did the trick! and since its a data.table object it seems to scale well with the problem size.

Answer (score 1):

A quick answer using `dplyr` is

```
library(dplyr)
DataFrame <- data_frame(ID,Time,y1,State)
output <- DataFrame %>% 
    group_by(ID) %>% # group the data by ID
    mutate(StateL = lead(State)) %>% # create a lead variable called StateL
    filter(State != StateL) %>% # subset the case where the state change at t+1
    mutate(transState = paste(State, "->", StateL)) %>% # crate a variable transState 
    select(c(ID, transState, y1)) ## select the vaiables to keep
output
##  # A tibble: 3 x 3
##  # Groups:   ID [2]
##       ID transState    y1
##    <dbl>      <chr> <dbl>
##  1 12232     a -> b   4.5
##  2 12232     b -> a   3.4
##  3 14452     c -> b   0.5
##
```

Comment: Great, thanks! But how scalable is the dplyr package? I ask because my true database is 1000.000s of individuals long...